# Meteor collection update with traditional id

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Im trying to do a simple update

```
Collection.update(id, {$set:{name:value}});
```

or even

```
Collection.update({'_id':id}, {$set:{name:value}});
```

But the collection won't update if the `id` is a traditional mongodb id. It only seems to work with meteors own implentation of unique id's. How can I remedy this. Is it possible for meteor to accept mongo's own id structure?

Comment: Is your `id` variable a string or ObjectId?  A string value like `502c7550bc3820529d81a9bd` won't match `ObjectId("502c7550bc3820529d81a9bd")`.

Comment: Meteor doesn't know what an `ObjectId` is `ReferenceError: ObjectId is not defined`

Comment: Hrm, appears that may be the case, though it seems odd to break a default feature that would be used to access existing MongoDB data :(. There is an open issue in the Meteor github queue: [update() broken when working with preexisting mongodb records using ObjectId()](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/61), which seems the same problem you are trying to solve.  Perhaps worth asking on the [meteor-talk google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/meteor-talk) as well.

Comment: Fixed since Meteor 0.5.7 in Feb 2013. http://www.meteor.com/blog/2013/02/21/meteor-057-major-scaling-update-new-ddp-version-ejson

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's possible to convert your ID into a mongodb object (on the server side) by using new ObjectID and then do the update. :

```
var ObjectID, require;

require = __meteor_bootstrap__.require;

ObjectID = require("mongodb").ObjectID;

Meteor.methods({
  SomeUpdate: function(upd) {
    var id;
    id = new ObjectID(upd['_id']);
    return SomeDB.update({
      _id: id
    }, {
      $set: {
        field: value
      }
    }, function(res) {
      return console.log(res);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: It is also possible to put the objectid implentation into the mongodb package using `new MongoDB.BSONPure.ObjectID` while attaching a `var require = __meteor_bootstrap__.require;
var MongoDB = require("mongodb");` and it would work on the client side when the update is done on the server end of things as long as the objectid is passed as a string inbetween

Answer (score 7):

You're right: Meteor's DDP protocol doesn't support non-JSON types such as Mongo `ObjectId`. We know this is a problem: it's our [oldest open issue](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/61) and it's on [our roadmap](https://trello.com/card/official-ddp-specification/508721606e02bb9d570016ae/53).

While there are definitely some "easy" quick fixes that would resolve this issue, we'd prefer to do this in the context of extending our protocol to handle other non-JSON types (dates, binary blobs, etc) rather than a specific short-term hack.