# With Meteor, how can I update a document based on MongoDB's ObjectID()?

Tags: meteor

I created a child array of objects in a document. Each of these array objects have:

```
children: [
    {
        _id: ObjectID("lkajsdflkajdsf"),
        title: "Something"
    }, ...
]
```

I'm getting ObjectId undefined error when trying to update a document:

```
Category.update(
    { "_id": "C2Rcjivw96htJSHRq", "children._id":  ObjectId("1c46382a25d3888165dd338a") },
    { "$set": { "children.$.title": "Hello World" }}
);
```

As you can see I'm attempting to update a specific array object by it's associated _id. This does not work. I was reading this thread: [Meteor collection update with traditional id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11979403/meteor-collection-update-with-traditional-id)

But it's a little outdated, and I'm also getting errors when trying to use it.

Is there a solid method for handling things in this fashion? I can do this in Mongo shell with no problem, but not through Meteor methods.

Thanks!

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#up._S_set also where do you update collection , server/client?

Comment: In this case the server because I'm passing multiple selectors. Tried on the client and it wouldn't allow me.

Comment: @yoK0 The problem here is my _id field inside the child array is an Object, not a string. I'm getting ReferenceError: ObjectID is not defined.

Comment: Use .toString method

Comment: I'm actually running into a ton of problems when dealing with ObjectId type. When generating the categories I changed to new Meteor.Collection.ObjectID()._str to just use it as a string. Now I'm studying up on the dangers of this since there's no technical duplicate checking... not that the chances of duplicate strings generated from that are common... just still learning.